# How to start/stop bundles in OSGI based web application

Tags: java, osgi

Usually we start/stop bundles via OSGI console, but for web application, how to do that once it's deployed in a container ?

Regards,

Setya

Answer (score 1):

Also not sure if I got you right, but anyway:

I think it depends on how you deploy a OSGi web application. The only way I already did was that I ran Tomcat within the OSGi context. Then Tomcat scans for bundles with a ".war" ending, so its basically started as soon as it's deployed and you can control it normally via the OSGi console

Answer (score 0):

not sure If I got you right, but...

Mostly applications are started just after deployment(war or eclipse)... you don't need to do anything.

but in case you want to you can do exactly the same thing you do to bundles... go to the web console of your chosen AS and start it there.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're using - please update question with container/framework details.

Otherwise, using Karaf you may simply SSH into the framework's shell and execute commands as normal.

Another alternative would be to use [WebConsole](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html) from Apache Felix - this gives you a lot of control wrt bundles (you can even upload to deploy), and also gives you an embedded shell.  It's quite [extensible](http://felix.apache.org/site/extending-the-apache-felix-web-console.html), you can write plugins to create new tabs etc.  (AFAIK this will run fine in any framework).